# Set of simple predictable processes is a vector space

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I have a question, which is probably very easy for you to answer.

How can I show that the set of simple predictable processes a vector space is? It's clear that I only have to show that the sum of two such processes again a simple predictable process is, which seems to be easy to show but is quite tricky in my point of view cause I'm not sure how to build a suitable sequence of stopping times.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Isn't that similar to the proof that measurable functions are closed under addition ?

Answer (score 3):

Let $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ and $(Y_t)_{t \geq 0}$ simple predictable processes, i.e.

$$\begin{align*} X_t &= 1_{\{t=0\}} A_0 + \sum_{k=1}^m 1_{\{S_k<t \leq T_k\}} A_k \\
Y_t &= 1_{\{t=0\}} B_0 + \sum_{j=1}^n 1_{\{U_j<t \leq V_j\}} B_j \end{align*}$$

where $S_k<T_k$, $U_k<V_k$ are stopping times and $A_k$ are $\mathcal{F}_{S_k}$, $B_k$ are $\mathcal{F}_{U_k}$-measurable bounded random variables. Obviously, this implies

$$X_t + Y_t = 1_{\{t=0\}} (A_0+B_0) + \sum_{k=1}^m 1_{\{S_k<t \leq T_k\}} A_k+ \sum_{j=1}^n 1_{\{U_k<t \leq V_k\}} B_k.$$

Note that this already shows that $(X_t+Y_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a simple process. In fact, we can choose

$$\begin{align*} P_k &:= \begin{cases} S_k, & k=1,\ldots,m \\ U_k, & k=m+1,\ldots,m+n \end{cases} \\ R_k &:= \begin{cases} T_k, & k=1,\ldots,m \\ V_k, & k=m+1,\ldots,m+n \end{cases} \\ C_k &:= \begin{cases} A_k & k=1,\ldots,m \\ B_k & k=m+1,\ldots,m+n \end{cases}\end{align*}$$

and $C_0 := A_0+B_0$. Then

$$X_t+Y_t = 1_{\{t=0\}} C_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{m+n} C_k 1_{\{P_k<t \leq R_k\}}.$$

---

**Edit:** To make the sequence of stopping times increasing, we can argue as follows: Let

$$X_t = \sum_{k=1}^m 1_{\{S_k<t \leq S_{k+1}\}} A_k$$

and

$$Y_t = \sum_{j=1}^n 1_{\{U_j<t \leq U_{j+1}\}} B_j.$$

For $k \in \{1,\ldots,m\}$ and $j \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ set

$$V_{k,j} := \min\{S_k, U_j\}.$$ Note that $V_{k,j} \leq V_{k',j'}$ for $k \leq k'$ and $j \leq j'$. Define iteratively (with $T_0:=0$)

$$T_i(\omega) := \inf\left\{ V_{k,j}(\omega); V_{k,j}(\omega)>T_{i-1}(\omega), k \in \{1,\ldots,m\}, j \in \{1,\ldots,n\} \right\}$$

for $i \leq mn$. This defines a sequence of non-decreasing stopping times and we can write

$$X_t+ Y_t = \sum_{i=1}^{mn} C_i 1_{\{T_i<t \leq T_{i+1}\}}$$

where

$$C_i := (X_t+Y_t)  1_{\{T_i<t \leq T_{i+1}\}} = \sum_{k=1}^m A_k 1_{\{S_k<t \leq S_{k+1}\}} 1_{\{T_i<t \leq T_{i+1}\}} + \sum_{j=1}^n B_j 1_{\{U_j<t \leq U_{j+1}\}} 1_{\{T_i<t \leq T_{i+1}\}}.$$

Comment: The definition in Protter's book also wants that $T_k = S_{k+1}$. This would result in $T_0\leq \dots\leq T_m$. He implicitly claims the simple predictable processes to be a linear space, too, but I fail to see how? I tried to order the stopping times $T_0\wedge V_0, \dots T_0\wedge V_n, \dots,T_m\wedge V_0,\dots, T_m\wedge V_n$. Any quick comment on that based on your answer?

Comment: @Ramen Assuming $T_k = S_{k+1}$ is not a problem, because we can always insert artificially a term of the form $0 \cdot 1_{\{T_k < t \leq S_{k+1}\}}$, and then we get a representation which does the job. What exactly is clear about proving that it is a linear space? This is exactly what my answer is about, isn't it?

Comment: Your choice of sequences $(P_k)$ and $(R_k)$ might not satisfy $R_k\leq P_j$ for any $j$ for some $k$, so where exactly would you introduce the artificial term? I think the problem is not assuming that $T_0\leq \dots\leq T_m$, $V_0\leq \dots\leq V_n$ and $T_k=S_{k+1}$ and $V_k=U_{k+1}$, but, after doing that, finding $R_0\leq\dots\leq R_p$ such that setting $R_k = P_{k+1}$ makes your representation equal $X+Y$. There might be some $T_k$ and $V_j$ that are not in the order relation i.e. not comparable, and you'd need to decompose the stopping times into sortable parts right?

Comment: For deterministic times you could just arrange them like e.g. $t_0\leq s_0\leq s_1\leq s_2\leq t_1\leq s_3\dots \leq t_m$ and be done. The point-wise order becomes trivial for deterministic times.

Comment: @Ramen I see, thanks. Your suggestion from your first comment sounds reasonable then.

Comment: Well, I didn't manage to go through with it. But if you were to, and wanted to explain, I think a second answer would be the perfect place to do so ;) (as the question didn't specify which definition of simple predictable processes to use). Thank you anyway!

Comment: @Ramen Well, where exactly you didn't get through? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I put the stopping times from my first comment in a matrix but didn't find a way to go through them that would order them... You start with $T_0\wedge V_0$, but do e.g. both $T_0\wedge V_1$, $T_0\wedge V_2$ go before $T_1\wedge V_0$ etc? I can't write an "algorithm" to answer that question...

Comment: @Ramen There is no deterministic way to order them; the order will in general depend on $\omega$, e.g. it may happen that $T_0 \wedge V_1(\omega)< T_1 \wedge V_0(\omega)$ for some $\omega$ whereas $T_0 \wedge V_1(\omega')> T_1 \wedge V_0(\omega')$ for some $\omega'$. I added some stuff to my answer, take a look whether it helps you.

Comment: Yes thank you, that's exactly what I needed...